# i have code like this:My dropdown button should reflect the data which i have entered in the input text field

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<!--Search Bar-->
    <div class="dropdown" style=margin-left:500px;margin-top:-40px>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown_coins" data-toggle="dropdown" >
         Set Location
        </button>
        <div  class="dropdown-menu" style=margin-top:20px>
            
                <input type="search" class="form-control" id='locName' placeholder="Search Location" style=margin-top:-60px>
            </form>
           
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--AutoComplete Search bar-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(function() {
        $("#locName").autocomplete({
            source: [
                "Adugodi",
                "Arekere",
                "Attiguppe",
                "Yelahanka"
    
            ],
            minLength: 1,
            function(event) {
                var value = event.getAttribute('value')
                var locName = document.getElementById("locName").value;
                if (value.includes('&')) {
                    value = value.replace("&", "%26");
                }
                if (locName == "") {
                    alert("Please Select your Location");
                } else {
                    window.location = "http://www.example.com
                }
                return false;
            }
    
        });
    });
    </script>
```

i have implemented auto complete search bar in my website.onclick of dropdown button my input search field will appear in that user can enter the data.after entering the location my drop down button should reflect the same data which i have entered in the input text field but here my drop down button is displaying again select location.kindly help me out of this am new to this field

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors -  tag is missing.  There is no closing quotes and ; after example.com.  I could not understand the value part in autocomplete and it gave errors as well. So I have commented that out. Rest is working. Hope this helps..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
             setLocation();
         });

            var cities = [
                "Adugodi",
                "Arekere",
                "Attiguppe",
                "Yelahanka"
            ];             

         function setLocation() {
            $( "#locName" ).autocomplete({
               source: cities,
               minLength: 1,
               autoFocus:true,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                //var value = event.getAttribute('value');
                var locName = document.getElementById("locName").value;
                //if (value.includes('&')) {
                //    value = value.replace("&", "%26");
                //}
                console.log( ui.item.label);
                if (locName === "") {
                    alert("Please Select your Location");
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("locName").value = ui.item.label;
                    document.getElementById("dropdown_coins").innerHTML =  "Set Location - " + ui.item.label;

                    window.location = "http://www.example.com";
                }
                return false;

            }
            });                 
         }

         function checkLocation() {
            var locName = document.getElementById("locName").value;  
            if (locName === "") {
                alert("Please Select your Location");
                document.getElementById("locName").focus();
            } else {
                var n = cities.includes(locName);
                if(!n) {
                    alert("Sorry! No such location. Please select location.");
                    document.getElementById("locName").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("dropdown_coins").innerHTML =  " Set Location ";
                    document.getElementById("locName").focus();
                }
                setLocation();
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
    <div class="dropdown" style=margin-left:500px;margin-top:40px>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown_coins" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="checkLocation();" >Set Location</button>
        <div  class="dropdown-menu" style=margin-top:20px>
            <form>
                <input type="search" class="form-control" id='locName' placeholder="Search Location" style=margin-top:-60px>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have problem with my drop down button..my dropdown button need to fetch the data which i have entered in input text field..kindly help me out of this

Comment: in place of set location.. the input  which i have entered in the input text field should reflect the same in the set location also

Comment: Edited... Now the selected item label is shown in both places - in the textbox as well as button.

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote the same... Thanks.

Comment: everthing is ok but after location is fixed my page is not redirecting to : window.location = "http://www.citycontact.in/MyDealers.php?id="+value+"&locName="+locName; this page

Comment: You should check whether you are getting the 'value' or not. And also it needs to be ui.item.label and not locName in the link.  So the link will be "https://www.citycontact.in/MyDealers.php?id="+value+"&locName="+ui.item.label

Comment: redirection is not happening